# Setting up Cygnus-PostgreSQL for historical data persistance

Tags: postgresql, fiware-cygnus

Now that I have a real device (LWM2M -using wakaama implementation) running and sending data to Orion (I can confirm from server log, `'Observers created successfully'`), I want to proceed with historical data storage.

I am not sure how to start. Using `docker-compose` file to start all services. I already have `postgres` image pulled and running. Would like to use it for persistence.

1. I guess I need to create the db schema to use for storage, any link to `cygnus-postgres` installation/persistence would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone be looking for how to go about similar situation as I did (above refers), I found the explanations [here](https://smartsdk-recipes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data-management/cygnus/ha/readme/#customisations) the customisations section very helpful, please read it.